# Domain of inverse trigonometric function

Tags: functions, trigonometry

I was able to understand the domain of individual inverse trigonometric functions in my book, however it also has some questions like: $\sec^{-1} x -\tan^{-1} x$ and I need to find the domain of the function, which I am not able to do.

In other questions like this, $\cos^{-1}x + \cos x$ I simply, found the intersection between the two trig functions and found it to be the domain. Is this just a fluke, if so what is correct method as in my book and due to my weak google-fu I am not able to find a solution.

> What is the domain of $\sec^{-1} x - \tan^{-1} x$?

Comment: Have you tried with drawing a graph in Desmos?

Comment: You are correct in your observations that the domain is simply the intersection of each of the individual domains (when adding and subtracting functions, that is).

Comment: @AndreasAlmgren Just downloaded the app, thanks for recommendation

Comment: Understood my mistake, I was only using principal graphs for all my work. Seeing Desmos drawing it  for me made it obvious. Thanks for help.